# How to get the difference between two arrays of objects

Tags: php

I have 2 array of objects, for example

```
$arr1 = [
  (new MyClass())->setId(1),
  (new MyClass())->setId(2),
  (new MyClass())->setId(3),
];

$arr2 = [
  (new MyClass())->setId(1),
  (new MyClass())->setId(2),
];
```

I'd need to find the difference between these 2 arrays, in this example I'd need to get an array with a single element, the one with id == 3.

I know I should use array_udiff (maybe) but I couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following logic might help:

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    public $id = null;

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }
}

$arr1 = [
    (new MyClass())->setId(1),
    (new MyClass())->setId(2),
    (new MyClass())->setId(3),
];

$arr2 = [
    (new MyClass())->setId(1),
    (new MyClass())->setId(2),
];

$difference = array_udiff($arr1, $arr2,
    function ($objOne, $objTwo) {
        return $objOne->id - $objTwo->id;
    }
);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [2] => MyClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
        )

)
```

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/TkXVp)

Comment: Then use `strcmp()`?

Comment: you could use [following](https://3v4l.org/EuDqs) to compare strings

Comment: for strings I did return strcmp($objOne->getId(), $objTwo->getId()) <=> 0; thanks @noam

Comment: @lucifer, guilty as charged... but I figured the code speaks for itself ;-)